# Google Play Console - не удалось подтвердить личность

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

На днях зарегистрировался на Гугл Плей Консоль. Сделал взнос 25$, ввёл реальные данные о себе и загрузил скан паспорта, для проверки личности.

Через пару дней пришел отказ:

> Hello,
>
> Your identity documentation couldn’t be verified.
>
> You have reached the maximum number of verification attempts. Contact
>   the Play Console team to request a refund.

На мой вопрос, пояснить причину отказа, ответили:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer support.    We are unable
>   to verify your ID to complete your Play Console registration and we
>   have refunded your registration fee to your original form of payment. 
>   Please note that your account will still be accessible but you won't
>   be able to publish any apps.   Please let me know if you have any
>   additional questions.

Как я понял, ТП пинать смысла нет, т.к. даже не ответили (или я криво перевел), в чем конкретно возникла проблема идентификации моей личности.

**Хочу загрузить пару своих приложений в гугл плей, но как теперь мне это сделать?**

Comment: Та же история. Было всего две попытки, один раз выслал скан водительского удостоверения, второй раз скан паспорта. Вторая попытка висела в обработке около трех недель. Результат - мы не можем установить вашу личность. Техподдержка шлет только ссылки на справочники и прямой ответ на вопрос "что делать дальше" не даёт. Меня нигде не банили, я ничего не нарушал, вообще первый раз вышел в свет, и такой тупик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему.

- Зарегистрировал второй аккаунт. Использовал те же данные и карту для оплаты, что и при первой регистрации.
- Снова загрузил скан паспорта для подтверждения личности, но опять отказали в регистрации. Зато в этот раз была возможность пройти подтверждение личности повторно.
- На второй попытке решил загрузить скан водительских прав и буквально за сутки мне подтвердили регистрацию.

Comment: А деньги вернули?

Answer (score 0):

Вам же написали:

> You have reached the maximum number of verification attempts.

Не понимаю, как можно не пройти верификацию с первого раза, ну на крайний случай со второго. А у вас было много попыток (судя по всему). Вот и отказали вам.

Попробуйте просто зарегать новый аккаунт.

Comment: Была только одна попытка, после которой и получил этот отказ.

Где-то тут же на stackoverflow прочитал, что новые аккаунты регистрировать не запрещено. После того как вернут средства за первый аккаунт, удалю с него всю информацию о себе и зарегистрирую новый.

Comment: @artur_mm Все данные при регистрации должны быть из "одного места". Т.е. в паспорте написана Россия, значит карта, которой вы оплачиваете 25$ должна быть от Российского банка, ваш IP должен быть Российским и т.п.

Comment: @artur_mm И если вас ранее уже банили в гугле, то вы не сможете больше пройти верификацию, да же на новых аккаунтах.