# Play console. Регистрация человека, проживающего не в Украине

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Есть аккаунт разработчика, при регистрации в качестве страны была указана Польша (я сейчас там проживаю), номер телефона - польский, а вот карта с которой была произведена оплата - украинская. Что я только не высл им в качестве документа который подтверждает мою личность, всего было 6 попыток и меня заблокировали. Сейчас общаюсь с тех. поддержкой и мне будут возвращать деньги за лицензию.

Мое гражданство - Украина. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие данные нужно указывать при регистрации аккаунта разработчика и карту какой страны использовать при оплате ?

Comment: Дубликаты? [Google Play Console - не удалось подтвердить личность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091724/); [Google play console. Регистрация россиянина проживающего не в России](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528155/)